# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Ok, So basically We use webpack to bundle our resources before deployment. However, now we want to also bundle our sass files through webpack is it simplifies our build process.it was going well, but now bundle.js is too big to deploy on production so I wanted to split bundle.js and styling files. I don't much know about plugins and all ,so I searched a little bit and found that mini-css-extract-plugin lets me split style files into a new file. So I went and tweaked the web-pack.config file according to the docs of
mini-css-extract-plugin but I am getting so many errors. Can somebody guide me to split styles file and extract it from bundle.js?

error :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at insertStyleElement (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:309:15)    at addStyle (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:424:13)
    at modulesToDom (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:297:18)      
    at module.exports.module.exports (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:455:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:206:14)    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:21:30)    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\normalize.css\normalize.css:88:10) 
    at Module._compile (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at evalModuleCode (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:61:10)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:166:21
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
    at eval (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:321:9
    at TaskRunner.run (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:48:7)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:227:18)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1409:36
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1405:32
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:675:18
 @ ./src/app.js 10:0-37

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at insertStyleElement (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:309:15)
    at addStyle (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:424:13)  
    at modulesToDom (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:297:18)
    at module.exports.module.exports (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:455:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:206:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:21:30)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\react-dates\lib\css\_datepicker.css:88:10)
    at Module._compile (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at evalModuleCode (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:61:10)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:166:21
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
    at eval (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:321:9
    at TaskRunner.run (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:48:7)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:227:18)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1409:36
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1405:32
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:675:18
 @ ./src/components/ExpenseForm.js 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/AddExpensePage.js
 @ ./src/routers/AppRouter.js
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./src/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at insertStyleElement (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:309:15)
    at addStyle (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:424:13)
    at modulesToDom (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:297:18)
    at module.exports.module.exports (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:455:25)       
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:206:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:21:30)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\style-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\src\styles\styles.scss:88:10)
    at Module._compile (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at evalModuleCode (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:61:10)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:166:21
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
    at eval (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:321:9
    at TaskRunner.run (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:48:7)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:227:18)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1409:36
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1405:32
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at D:\ReactJs-Projects\Expensify-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:675:18
 @ ./src/app.js 11:0-30
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require("path");
//const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = env => {
    const isProduction = env === "production";
    //const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css");

    console.log("env", env);
    return {
        entry: "./src/app.js",
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
            filename: "bundle.js",
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: {
                                publicPath: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
                            },
                        },
                        "style-loader",
                        "css-loader", 
                        "sass-loader", 
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "styles.css",
            }),
        ],
        // plugins: [CSSExtract],
        devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "cheap-module-eval-source-map", 

        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
            historyApiFallback: true,
        },
    };
};
```

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "expensify-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "Viral Thaker",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "live-server public/",
        "build:dev": "webpack",
        "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
        "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
        "start": "npm run dev-server",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "css-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "jest": "^26.4.1",
        "live-server": "^1.2.1",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.0",
        "validator": "^13.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.10.0",
        "webpack": "^4.44.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a conflict between all your CSS loaders. First thing I would try is removing `style-loader`.

Comment: According to the documentation you should not use style-loader and mini-css-extract-plugin together: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#recommended

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Camilo suggested there was this `"style-loader"` which was somehow conflicting to the plugin but anyway as I am separating CSS files I don't need inline CSS so I completely removed it from the loader and the error was completely gone and it gave me a new build with separate CSS file

Anyone, having the same problem in future just look for your loader whether its conflicting

Comment: how can we know if is conflucting

Comment: The critical info here is `style-loader` is used to insert all your CSS into the DOM via JS, whereas the loader in `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` is designed to add a `link` element in your `head` element to the separately built CSS file. They are fundamentally incompatible and therefore you should remove one.

Comment: Problem appears when I try to use both loader css-loader and style-loader. I have removed the style-loader, and everything is fine :)

Comment: In my case after migrating from Angular 7 to Angular 13, I ended up with two different versions  of  `css-loader` in my `package-lock.json`. I remove the older one and problem was solved

Answer (score 5):

Due to **style-loader** the error will happen, after removing this it gone.

**Error:**

```
    rules:[{
        test:/\.(css)$/,
        use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'style-loader','css-loader']
    },]
```

**Solution:**

```
    rules:[{
        test:/\.(css)$/,
        use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader']
    },]
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the following in webpack.mix.js

```
   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps();
```

to

```
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error on Gatsby when I tried to add fonts under src folder. The reason for the alert originated in my improper path for importing. I had appended ".." to the path inside the main CSS file, which was redundant - it was reading from the public folder. So, I believe going over the paths on imports may indicate the faulty code.