# Webpack + sass-loader + mini-css-extract-plugin error

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-5, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm new to webpack and just trying to set up step-by-step a test project.

I'm currenctly stuck on processing sass stylesheets and the problem is surely related to the `mini-css-extract-plugin` package since if I remove its loader from the css/sass rule I got no error (and no outputted separate file of course).

My previous step involved simple css stylesheet and everything was ok (`mini-css-extract-plugin` was already there), but when ported to sass something started giving the error.

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");


const config = {
    entry: [
        './src/js/index.js',
        './src/sass/index.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'js/main.[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Management',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/html/index.template.html'),
        }),
        new WebpackManifestPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/main.[contenthash].css"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
};

if (config.mode == 'production') {
    config.optimization = {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

#### the error

```
node@e6292f1e9550:~/app$ npm run build

> webpack-demo@1.0.0 build
> webpack

asset js/main.fbe92ae22f4b65b3f77d.js 10.5 KiB [emitted] [immutable] (name: main)
asset index.html 307 bytes [emitted] [compared for emit]
asset manifest.json 90 bytes [emitted] [compared for emit]
orphan modules 9.78 KiB (javascript) 972 bytes (runtime) [orphan] 15 modules
cacheable modules 287 bytes
  ./src/js/index.js 248 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/sass/index.scss 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/sass/index.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: document is not defined
    at tryRunOrWebpackError (/home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:88:9)
    at __webpack_require_module__ (/home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5058:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5015:18)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5086:20
    at symbolIterator (/home/node/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3485:9)
    at done (/home/node/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3527:9)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/node/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4993:43
    at symbolIterator (/home/node/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3482:9)
    at timesSync (/home/node/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)
-- inner error --
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.insertStyleElement (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js:5:17)
    at Object.domAPI (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js:59:30)
    at addElementStyle (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js:57:21)
    at modulesToDom (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js:41:21)
    at module.exports (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js:78:25)
    at Module.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/src/sass/index.scss:42:120)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:441:11
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/node/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5060:39
    at tryRunOrWebpackError (/home/node/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:83:7)

Generated code for /home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/src/sass/index.scss
 1 | __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
 2 | /* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
 3 | /* harmony export */   "default": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)
 4 | /* harmony export */ });
 5 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_injectStylesIntoStyleTag_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
 6 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_injectStylesIntoStyleTag_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_injectStylesIntoStyleTag_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
 7 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleDomAPI_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js");
 8 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleDomAPI_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleDomAPI_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
 9 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertBySelector_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js");
10 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertBySelector_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertBySelector_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__);
11 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_setAttributesWithoutAttributes_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/setAttributesWithoutAttributes.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/setAttributesWithoutAttributes.js");
12 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_setAttributesWithoutAttributes_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_setAttributesWithoutAttributes_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__);
13 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertStyleElement_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js");
14 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertStyleElement_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertStyleElement_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__);
15 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleTagTransform_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleTagTransform.js */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleTagTransform.js");
16 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleTagTransform_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleTagTransform_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__);
17 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__ = __webpack_require__(/*! !!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./index.scss */ "/home/node/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/home/node/app/src/sass/index.scss");
18 | /* harmony reexport (unknown) */ var __WEBPACK_REEXPORT_OBJECT__ = {};
19 | /* harmony reexport (unknown) */ for(const __WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__ in _node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__) if(__WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__ !== "default") __WEBPACK_REEXPORT_OBJECT__[__WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__] = () => _node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__[__WEBPACK_IMPORT_KEY__]
20 | /* harmony reexport (unknown) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, __WEBPACK_REEXPORT_OBJECT__);
21 | 
22 |       
23 |       
24 |       
25 |       
26 |       
27 |       
28 |       
29 |       
30 |       
31 | 
32 | var options = {};
33 | 
34 | options.styleTagTransform = (_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleTagTransform_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default());
35 | options.setAttributes = (_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_setAttributesWithoutAttributes_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default());
36 | 
37 |       options.insert = _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertBySelector_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default().bind(null, "head");
38 |     
39 | options.domAPI = (_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_styleDomAPI_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default());
40 | options.insertStyleElement = (_node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_insertStyleElement_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default());
41 | 
42 | var update = _node_modules_style_loader_dist_runtime_injectStylesIntoStyleTag_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"], options);
43 | 
44 | 
45 | 
46 | 
47 |        /* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (_node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"] && _node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"].locals ? _node_modules_css_loader_dist_cjs_js_node_modules_sass_loader_dist_cjs_js_index_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"].locals : undefined);
48 | 

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 539 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539242/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-mini-css-extract-plugin-dist-loader-js), and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63543929) pointed me in the right direction: `style-loader` conficts with the other loaders (not sure which one) so I just removed it and webpack started compiling correctly.